# Python : append/merge dicts to pandas in a pythonic way

Tags: python, data-binding, pandas

I'm new to python, I'm trying to append result from  my iteration loop that give out different number of keys each time in the loop .. something like

```
 result i=1 => {key1:a, key2:b}
 result i=2 => {key2:c, key3:d , key4:z}
```

I want my result to be a dataframe something like

```
key1  key2    key3  key4
a       b    None  None
None    c      d     z
```

what is the most efficient way to do something

```
for i in range(10):
    do something 
    result dict

combine
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either append each dict to your DataFrame as you loop:

```
for i in range(10):
    # create dict
    df.append( created_dict )
```

or create a list of the created dicts and pass this into the DataFrame constructor

```
df = pd.DataFrame(my_list_of_dicts)
```

However, if you have a lot of dicts then appending to the list will become expensive and the first code snippet would be better.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might work:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: dic1 = {'key1':'a', 'key2':'b'}       

In [3]: dic2 = {'key2':'c', 'key3':'d' , 'key4':'z'}

In [4]: keys = sorted(dic1.viewkeys() | dic2.viewkeys())

In [5]: pd.DataFrame([[d.get(k) for k in keys]
                                         for d in (dic1, dic2)], columns=keys)                        
Out[5]: 
   key1 key2  key3  key4
0     a    b  None  None
1  None    c     d     z
```

Instead of using just `sorted` I'd suggest you to use [natural sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836710/does-python-have-a-built-in-function-for-string-natural-sort) for sorting such keys.